# Dataset for consumer digital media

Tags: demographics, media

I'm looking for a dataset that will help me determine a correlation between college major and media preferences i.e. genre.

Comment: That's too vague, please [edit]. Media preferences can be about hardware devices, genre can be about audio, video, ... And since you are talking about *college major* you probably want US data?